# sizeof returns different values for a struct when compiling different programs

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-memory, sizeof

I have 2 programs that share a header file. This header file defines a structure with a few members. There is then a #define: `#define STRUCTURE_SIZE sizeof(OUR_STRUCTURE)`.

This structure is then used in shared memory with `STRUCTURE_SIZE` being used for the `size` argument to `shmget()`.

Unfortunately, for the one program, STRUCTURE_SIZE ends up being 20758, while in the other one, it ends up being 20764. So when the second program tries to get the shared mem, `shmget()` returns EINVAL.

`uname -a`:

`Linux machine 2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.i686.PAE #1 SMP Thu Feb 11 07:05:37 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

`g++ --version`:

`g++ (GCC) 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)`

Comment: Post some code. What is OUR_STRUCTURE?

Comment: Definition of OUR_STRUCTURE is needed.

Comment: I would, but I'm a lowly intern, and don't know if I really should. This structure is the heart of the system, essentially.

Comment: You can always anonymise the member and type names.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A few possibilities:

- you're compiling the two programs with different compilers and/or compiler switches
- you have another header which appears before the header in question in one of the programs and this messes with `#pragma pack` or similar and doesn't restore the setting
- a type that is used in the shared struct is defined differently in the two programs

(Note: the last two points can be applied recursively to any other structs which are used within the problem struct.)

Comment: `#pragma pack(8)` fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be a packing or alignment issue. Find out how to tell your compiler how it should align structures.

Answer (score 2):

Other possibilities:

- The set of defines used in the two compilations differs, and the structure is defined conditionally on these defines
- Some types can have different sizes in kernel and user space (this is rare, but it can happen)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to gain some understanding by writing some code to check the offsets of field in `OUR_STRUCTURE` and print them out, using the two compilations in turn.  Break down the total struct size to determine the size caused by each of its fields.

```
struct OUR_STRUCTURE
{
  double d;
  other_structure other;
  bool flag;
};

OUR_STRUCTURE ours;
cout << &ours.d - &ours << endl;
cout << &ours.other - &ours << endl;
cout << &ours.flag - &ours << endl;
cout << &ours + sizeof(OUR_STRUCTURE) - &ours.flag << endl;
```